# How to left align a 32 bit integer?

Tags: c, integer, bit-manipulation

I have a 32 bit integer variable in hexadecimal format say `0x9B13488` or `0x1407E8`. Defaultly it is right aligned to `0x099B1348` or `0x001407E8`. But I want it to be left aligned to `0x9B134880` or `0x1407E800`. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Are you talking about printing the value without changing the variable content or about modifying the value in the variable? Hexadecimal format only makes sense in context of printing.

Comment: It is not clear if you need this on bit level, nibble level or byte level. And what do you mean "left aligned", is this a raw value or a string? Why do you need it moved? Please clarify.

Comment: @Lundin `0x001407E8 --> 0x1407E800` implies   not bit level. `0x099B1348 --> 0x9B134880` implies  not byte level. So, uncleanly, this is to be nibble level.

Comment: @Gerhardh i need to process the value and while doing that i need to make sure that is left aligned. Hexadecimal i am using it for printing as well initialising the variable

Comment: @Lundin i need it atleast nibble level

Comment: The shift stepwise by 1 bit could have been asked for too: 0x4444_789A to 0x8888_F134

Comment: @surajrgupta "i am using it for printing as well initialising the variable": --> Posting code that demonstrates this use would add clarity and would allow answers to provide even greater insight.

Comment: What is ff your number is, say `0x123`? Do you want to transform it to `0x12300000`? You question is somewhat unclear. Please [edit] and add more examples.

Comment: "I have a 32 bit integer variable in hexadecimal format" - there is the contradiction. A number doesn't have a format, although formats become relevant when we want to write a number down. Is this question therefore really about how to format a 32 bit `int`, and if so, then what do you really want to do?

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes i want it as 0x12300000 if at all compile takes it as 0x00000123 while initializing i want it manipulated as 0x12300000

Comment: @surajrgupta please [edit] your question and put all clarifications _there_.

Answer (score 8):

What you're really asking for is if the high-order 4 bits are set.  You can do this as follows:

```
uint32_t left_align(uint32_t value)
{
    if (value) {
        while ((value & 0xF0000000U) == 0) {
            value <<= 4;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

As long as the value is non-zero and the higher order 4 bits are 0, shift left by 4 until they are non-zero.

Comment: Might wish to add `if (value)` before and `return value;` after the loop.

Comment: @NominalAnimal what for?

Comment: @P__J__ To prevent an infinite loop

Comment: @Ctx how `if` before the `return` can prevent the while loop (considering the lack of the check) from being infinitive

Comment: @P__J__ Read carefully, "if before _and_ return value after the loop"

Comment: I meant, `if (value) while (!(value &0xF0000000U)) value <<= 4; return value;` might be preferable. I say *might*, because I see it as clearer expression of programmer intent, with fewer opportunities of bugs creeping in; better example for those learning to program. Actually, now that I think about it, I like `if (value) while (value < 0x10000000) value <<= 4; return value;` even more for those same reasons.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Makes sense.  I moved the 0 check out of the loop to make the intent more clear.

Comment: Although the `U` suffix in `0xF0000000U` not technically needed here, I see it adds clarity to the code.  Likely prevents some odd warning too with picky compilers.

Comment: @P__J__ Re: "0x.... are always U" is not supported  by the C spec C11 §6.4.4.1. The sign-ness of the type applied to the constant depends on its value.   `0x123` is an `int`, not `unsigned`.